# Get angular-cli to ng serve over HTTPS

Tags: angular, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, angular-cli

The following doesn't seem to do anything.

```
ng serve --ssl true --ssl-key <key-path> --ssl-cert <cert-path>
```

---

Creating the Certificate and key by providing them in the default ssl directory still does nothing.

It looks like `ng server` is completely ignoring the `--ssl` parameter and keeps saying `NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200.`

Comment: try ng serve --ssl 1 --ssl-key "ssl/local.brianflove.com.key" --ssl-cert "ssl/local.brianflove.com.crt"

Comment: I wrote a short doc (for local-dev-envs only) here: https://github.com/webia1/Frontend-Ecosystem/tree/main/Angular/Documentation/HTTPS

Answer (score 154, accepted):

## Angular CLI 6+

I've updated my own projects so I figured I can now update this answer too.

You'll now put the path to your key and certificate in your angular.json file as follows:

```
{
   "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
   "projects": {
       "<PROJECT-NAME>": {
           "architect": {
               "serve: {
                   "options": {
                       "sslKey": "<relative path from angular.json>/server.key",
                       "sslCert": "<relative path from angular.json>/server.crt",
                       ...
                   }, ...
               }, ...
           }, ...
       }, ...
   }, ...
}
```

And then you can run:

```
ng serve --ssl
```

If you want SSL on by default then you should add a *"ssl": true,* option immediately below the *sslKey* and *sslCert*.

You can find the angular.json schema at the [Angular CLI documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace).

## Old answer for Angular CLI 1.0.0+.

Angular-CLI now works with the SSL options. Like you've noted, you can manually select which key and cert you'd like to use with the command:

```
ng serve --ssl --ssl-key <key-path> --ssl-cert <cert-path>
```

If you'd like to set a default path for your key and cert then you can go into your .angular-cli.json file adjust the Defaults section accordingly:

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "defaults": {
        "serve": {
            "sslKey": "<relative path from .angular-cli.json>/server.key",
            "sslCert": "<relative path from .angular-cli.json>/server.crt",
            ...
        }, ...
    }, ...
}
```

And then you can run:

```
ng serve --ssl
```

If you want SSL on by default then you should add a *"ssl": true,* option immediately below the *sslKey* and *sslCert*.

Comment: "ssl" : "true" will start ssl by default

Comment: @Dominik, where to write "ssl" : "true"  . Can you tell me either in ng serve command or in angular-cli.json. Thank you

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr It would be another key-value pair inside the *serve* object. So it would go on the line beneath "sslCert": "<relative path from .angular-cli.json>/server.crt".

Answer (score 125):

You can use

```
--ssl
```

or

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "someapp:build",
            "ssl": true
          },
```

and an ssl cert will automatically be generated for you.

Then for Chrome to accept a self signed cert for localhost, set this flag: `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost`

You'll also need to import the cert into your Trusted Root Certificates.  To do this, click the cert error at top in Chrome then:

1. Click `certificate (invalid)`
2. Click the `Details` tab
3. Click `Copy to File...`
4. next next finish and export it somewhere.
5. start-> run-> `inetcpl.cpl`
6. click `Content` tab
7. click `Certificates`
8. click `Trusted Root Certication Authorities` tab
9. Click `Import` button
10. Import the cert
11. Re-run `ng serve --ssl`

Be aware, the cert only lasts one month.  At the end of that month you'll struggle to find a solution but I've already been through this and [here is the fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63814027/4055033)

Comment: With --ssl on a Mac I also needed to leave the --port flag off and run ng serve as an admin. sudo ng serve --ssl --host localdeveloper.whatever.com. Getting localdeveloper.whatever.com to resolve on a mac (meaning an additional localhost hosts file entry) requires aliasing, a topic for another s.o. question.

Comment: remove cash if didn't work

Comment: The code snippet that needs to be updated is in the `angular.json` file of your project. Hope this will help a lot of new angular developers.

Comment: Just an FYI but chrome removed the allow-insecure-localhost flag in version 119

Answer (score 38):

If you don't want to go for configurations just add `--ssl`

```
ng serve --ssl
```

Perfectly working, it will automatically create a certificate for you. Tested on chrome browser. It says "not trusted connection", but just proceed.

Hope this helps

Comment: Be aware, this cert only lasts one month.  When it expires you'll be running around all over the place looking for a fix.  I battled this so keep [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63814027/4055033)

Comment: `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost` FTW

Comment: @RubensFarias Hero

Comment: @PostImpatica What do you mean that the cert will only last one month? Isn't it updated every time I restart the app?

Answer (score 36):

JFYI, in Angular6 you have to put the conf in the options (in angular.json) :

```
"serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
        "browserTarget": "app:build",
        "ssl": true,
        "sslKey": "path to .key",
        "sslCert": "path to .crt"
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 31):

Very simple solution from [this page](https://brettmckenzie.net/2018/03/14/serving-your-angular-cli-app-locally-over-https/)

```
npm install browser-sync --save-dev
```

And then

```
ng serve --ssl true --ssl-key ./node_modules/browser-sync/certs/server.key --ssl-cert ./node_modules/browser-sync/certs/server.crt
```

Quick and bold)
Just used it in my angular cli 6.2.3 project

Comment: FYI, this still works great in the angular.json file but the paths have changed:

"ssl": true,
"sslKey": "/node_modules/browser-sync/certs/server.key",
"sslCert": "/node_modules/browser-sync/certs/server.crt",

Comment: As for latest angular: 12.0.5, node:v14.17.1,  browser-sync: ^2.26.14, command update as following:   ng serve --ssl true --ssl-key ./node_modules/browser-sync/certs/server.key --ssl-cert ./node_modules/browser-sync/certs/server.crt

Comment: It doesn't work. We have to "accept le risk" and https is always in red!

Answer (score 7):

IF you want to create your own certificate and add to the trusted keychain in MAC

We’ll be using OpenSSL to generate all of our certificates.

Step 1: Root SSL certificate

Step 2: Trust the root SSL certificate

Step 3: Domain SSL certificate

Step 4: Use your new SSL certificate

```
# Step 1: Root SSL certificate

    openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key 2048
    openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.pem
```

[image]

```
# Step 2: Trust the root SSL certificate
```

Before you can use the newly created Root SSL certificate to start issuing domain certificates, there’s one more step. You need to to tell your Mac to trust your root certificate so all individual certificates issued by it are also trusted.

Keychain Access on your Mac and go to the Certificates category in your System keychain. Once there, import the rootCA.pem using File > Import Items. Double click the imported certificate and change the “When using this certificate:” dropdown to Always Trust in the Trust section.

Your certificate should look something like this inside Keychain Access if you’ve correctly followed the instructions till now.

[image]

```
# Step 3: Domain SSL certificate
```

The root SSL certificate can now be used to issue a certificate specifically for your local development environment located at localhost.

Create a new OpenSSL configuration file server.csr.cnf so you can import these settings when creating a certificate instead of entering them on the command line.

```
[req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = dn

[dn]
C=US
ST=RandomState
L=RandomCity
O=RandomOrganization
OU=RandomOrganizationUnit
emailAddress=hello@example.com
CN = localhost
```

Create a v3.ext file in order to create a X509 v3 certificate. Notice how we’re specifying subjectAltName here.

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
```

Create a certificate key for localhost using the configuration settings stored in server.csr.cnf. This key is stored in server.key.

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out server.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -config <( cat server.csr.cnf )
```

A certificate signing request is issued via the root SSL certificate we created earlier to create a domain certificate for localhost. The output is a certificate file called server.crt.

```
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 500 -sha256 -extfile v3.ext
```

[image]

```
# Step 4 Use your new SSL certificate
```

You’re now ready to secure your localhost with HTTPS. Move the server.key and server.crt files to an accessible location on your server and include them when starting your server.

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "project-falcon:build",
            "ssl": true,
            "sslKey": "src/assets/sslcertificate/server.key",
            "sslCert": "src/assets/sslcertificate/server.crt"
          }
        }
```

**Clear the cache in Google chrome and restart the browser, also delete the cache and temp files in mac**

Now we can use `ng serve -o`

Reference

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec/

Answer (score 4):

You are correct. The current implementation does not take the ssl configuration options under account. I have created a [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/2089) that fixes this issue. However it has not been merged yet in the master at the time of this writing.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13918177)

Comment: The latest version of angular-cli fixes the issue. So to fix the issue all you have to do is upgrade to latest  angular-cli

Answer (score 2):

I think I actually stumbled onto a much easier way to generate, trust, and use some fresh certs with angular using [office-addin-dev-certs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-addin-dev-certs). Don't be fooled by the name, they work for any local development!

1. Run this command to generate the certs and click "Yes" to trust them when it prompts you:

   - `npx office-addin-dev-certs install --days 365`
2. The generated certs (`localhost.crt` and `localhost.key`) will be in your home folder `~\.office-addin-dev-certs`

   - Copy them to your angular project: `cp ~\.office-addin-dev-certs\localhost.* .`
3. Feed the certs to angular:

   - Run `ng serve --ssl --ssl-key localhost.key --ssl-cert localhost.crt`
   - Or add them to your `angular.json` so you can run `ng serve` as normal:

```json
"serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "configurations": {
        "development": {
            "browserTarget": "blank16:build:development",
            "ssl": true,
            "sslKey": "localhost.key",
            "sslCert": "localhost.crt"
        }
    },
    "defaultConfiguration": "development"
},
```

I also posted [a PowerShell script to automate the process on my blog](https://bradleycarey.com/posts/get-angular-cli-to-ng-serve-over-https/).

Answer (score 1):

Angular CLI 1.0.0+.

ng serve **--ssl 1** **--ssl-key** {{key-path}} **--ssl-cert** {{cert-path}}

Angular CLI 6+

ng serve **--ssl true** **--sslKey** {{key-path}} **--sslCert** {{cert-path}}

Change the values ​​in {{*-path}}, to the corresponding values.

Answer (score 0):

ref to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40190595/12537072

if ssl configuration exist on `package.json` same as below:

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve --ssl --ssl-cert %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem --ssl-key %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key",
  "start:fa": "ng serve --configuration=fa --ssl --ssl-cert %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem --ssl-key %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key",
  ...
},
```

use this: `npm run start`

to use run with different configuration, after define on package use: `npm run start:fa`

Answer (score -2):

It always advisable to provide the cert and ports to server team. They configure in server level. This way always good for production code.

The team will configure Cert and DNS mapping with domain.

so it turn in to HTTPS://your app domainname:your choosen port/