# Deploy Angular App with Tomcat Webserver

Tags: angular, tomcat, deployment, webserver, fallback

I have an **Angular App** that perfectly works on my Localhost. Now I want to **deploy** it on my **Tomcat 7 Server**, running on my Ubuntu Server.

Now the App is working, but the **URL is not displayed/working** and the **AppTitle** and **Favicon** is not visible

E.g. when I go to `http://myServerUrl.net/login` it returns `404`

I already know that has something to do with the **fallback** (see: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml)

But I do not really get **how I need to configure Tomcat** now, so that it will work.

Ah and my WebApp is directly under the ROOT folder of the webapps folder.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/40852931/5695162

Comment: I already did all that is described there, but I still have the errors.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346429/angular-app-deployed-on-tomcat-as-war/51721824 - there is a fallback described for 404 to redirect to index.html