# Cannot configure amazon-cognito-auth-js to angular 4 application with SAML Identity provider

Tags: angular, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook

I am trying to integrate SAML Service provider with AWS cognito pool.I have gone through lot of documents and tried to implement .However redirecting is not happening when i click on log in .[scenario is it should redirect to Microsoft login Page]
 Cognito pool and identity providers are configured correctly.
Problem comes when i need to authenticate from front end application 
could anyone please help me to rectify the same..?
here is my code

> step 1:

```
npm install amazon-cognito-auth-js --save
```

> step 2:add below line in angularcli.json

```
"../node_modules/amazon-cognito-auth-js/dist/amazon-cognito-auth.js",
"../node_modules/amazon-cognito-auth-js/dist/amazon-cognito-auth.min.js.map",
"../node_modules/amazon-cognito-auth-js/dist/aws-cognito-sdk.js"
```

> step3:app.component.ts

```
import {CognitoAuth} from 'amazon-cognito-auth-js';
```

> step 4:

```
authData = {
    ClientId : '2*********************u',
    AppWebDomain : 'https://myApplication***********.com',
    TokenScopesArray : ['email'], 
    RedirectUriSignIn : 'https//google.com',
    RedirectUriSignOut : 'https//google.com',
    IdentityProvider : 'SAML', // e.g. 'Facebook',
    UserPoolId : 'ap-south-1_****' // Your user pool id here
};
```

> step 5:in app.html

```
<button (click)="login()">click</button>
```

> step 6:

```
login() {
   var auth = new CognitoAuth(this.authData);
   console.log("hello");
   auth.userhandler = {
    onSuccess: function(result) {
        alert("Sign in success");       
    },
    onFailure: function(err) {
        alert("Error!");
    }
};
```

my problem comes here when i click on login button the page is not redirecting .Please help me

Comment: is there any output error in the console?

Comment: sadly no error..

Comment: I have a working example which is in pure js .I tries to convert it into Angular version but couldnt do it .

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(CognitoAuth)`?

Comment: here is git repo  https://github.com/UWFosterIT/aws-cognito/blob/master/static/index.html which is working properly but of pure javascript .

Comment: consoling CognitoAuth returning  a function CognitoAuth(data) {
    _classCallCheck(this, CognitoAuth).....}

Comment: also consoling auth returns an object with all specified data:--this.auth:-{"clientId":"***********","appWebDomain":"https://**********south-1.amazoncognito.com",....

Answer (score 3):

Check your `AppWebDomain`, `TokenScopesArray` and `IdentityProvider` authData values (check my comments below):

```
authData = {
    ClientId : '2*********************u',
    AppWebDomain : 'https://myApplication***********.com', // this should be from Cognito Console -> Your user pool -> App Integration -> Domain Name
    TokenScopesArray : ['email'], // this should be from Cognito Console -> Your user pool -> App Integration -> App Client Settings -> Allowed OAuth Scopes  
    RedirectUriSignIn : 'https//google.com',
    RedirectUriSignOut : 'https//google.com',
    IdentityProvider : 'SAML', // e.g. 'Facebook', // this should be from Cognito Console -> Your user pool -> Federation -> Identity Providers -> SAML -> Provider Name
    UserPoolId : 'ap-south-1_****' // Your user pool id here
};
```

Check [GitHub](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js) for more reference. From [AUTHORIZATION](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html) endpoint documentation, note that `identity_provider` can be either:

- For social sign-in the valid values are Facebook, Google, and
  LoginWithAmazon.
- For Amazon Cognito user pools, the value is COGNITO.
- For other identity providers this would be the name you assigned to
  the IdP in your user pool.

---

### Solution

The below-mentioned solution is for Google Sign-In in Angular 7.

```
> npm install -g @angular/cli
> ng new auth-app
Angular Routing: Yes
> cd auth-app
> ng g c login
> ng g c home
> ng g s cognito
> npm install --save amazon-cognito-auth-js
```

In **auth-app/src/app/cognito.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CognitoAuth } from 'amazon-cognito-auth-js';

@Injectable(
  {
  providedIn: 'root'
  }
)
export class CognitoService {

  authData: any;
  auth: any;
  session: any;

  constructor(private router : Router) {
    this.getAuthInstance();
  }

  getAuthInstance() {
    this.authData = {
      ClientId: '...',
      AppWebDomain: '...', 
      TokenScopesArray: ['openid', 'email', 'profile'],
      RedirectUriSignIn: 'https://localhost:4200/home',
      UserPoolId: '...',
      RedirectUriSignOut: 'https://localhost:4200',
      AdvancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag: false
    }

    this.auth = new CognitoAuth(this.authData);

    this.auth.userhandler = {
      onSuccess: session => {
        console.log('Signin success');
        this.signedIn(session);
      },
      onFailure: error => {
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
        this.onFailureMethod();
      }
    }

    //alert(this.router.url);
    //this.auth.useCodeGrantFlow();
    this.auth.parseCognitoWebResponse(this.router.url);
  }

  signedIn(session) {
    this.session = session;
  }

  onFailureMethod() {
    this.session = undefined;
  }

  get accessToken() {
    return this.session && this.session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
  }

  get isAuthenticated() {
    return this.auth.isUserSignedIn();
  }

  login() {
    this.auth.getSession();
    this.auth.parseCognitoWebResponse(this.router.url);
  }

  signOut() {
    this.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

In **auth-app/src/app/app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In **auth-app/src/app/login/login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CognitoService } from '../cognito.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private cognitoService : CognitoService, private router : Router) {
    if(!this.cognitoService.isAuthenticated) {
      console.log("Not authenticated")
    } else {
      console.log("Already authenticated")
      this.router.navigateByUrl(this.router.url + "/home");
    }
   }

  ngOnInit() { }

  loginWithGoogle() {
    this.cognitoService.login();
  }
}
```

In **auth-app/src/app/login/login.component.html**

```
<h1>Login</h1>

<button (click)="loginWithGoogle()">Login with Google</button>
```

In **auth-app/src/app/home/home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CognitoService } from '../cognito.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private cognitoService : CognitoService, private router : Router) {
    if(this.router.url.indexOf('?') !== -1) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(this.router.url.substring(0, this.router.url.indexOf('?')));
    } else {
      this.cognitoService.login();
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  printToken() {
    alert(this.cognitoService.accessToken);
  }

  signOut() {
    this.cognitoService.signOut();
  }
}
```

In **auth-app/src/app/home/home.component.html**

```
<button (click)="printToken()">Print Token</button>

<button (click)="signOut()">Signout</button>
```

In **auth-app/src/app/app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path:'', component: LoginComponent },
  { path:'home', component: HomeComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

To run the application with **HTTPS** (because Callback URL should be HTTPS for Cognito):

```
> npm install browser-sync --save-dev
> ng serve --ssl true --ssl-key /node_modules/browser-sync/lib/server/certs/server.key --ssl-cert /node_modules/browser-sync/lib/server/certs/server.crt
```

Please note that you should configure following Callback and signout URL in Cognito. Go to Cognito console -> Your user pool -> App Integration -> App Client settings

- Callback URL(s): https://localhost:4200/home
- Sign out URL(s): https://localhost:4200

Go to https://localhost:4200

References:

- https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js/issues/13
- https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53398097/1605917

Answer (score 0):

Try this

install the types so could have intellisense to amazon-sdk

> npm i @types/amazon-cognito-auth-js --save-dev

then change your login method to this

```
login() {
   const auth = new CognitoAuth(this.authData);
   console.log("hello");
   auth.userhandler.onSuccess = (result) => {
        alert("Sign in success");       
   };
   auth.userhandler.onFailure = (err) => {
        alert("Error!");
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way... working code for me.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CognitoAuth } from 'amazon-cognito-auth-js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  auth: any;
  constructor() {
    //
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.auth = this.initCognitoSDK();
    const curUrl = window.location.href;
    this.auth.parseCognitoWebResponse(curUrl);
  }

  initCognitoSDK() {
    const authData = {
      ClientId: 'xyz',
      AppWebDomain: 'xyz', 
      TokenScopesArray: ['openid'],
      RedirectUriSignIn: 'xyz',
      UserPoolId: 'xyz',
      RedirectUriSignOut: 'xyz',
      IdentityProvider: 'xyz',
      AdvancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag: false
    };

    const auth = new CognitoAuth(authData);

    auth.userhandler = {
      onSuccess: (result) => {
        alert('Sign in success');
        this.showSignedIn(result);
      },
      onFailure: (err) => {
        alert('Sign in failed');
      }
    };
    auth.useCodeGrantFlow();
    return auth;
  }

  login() {
    this.auth.getSession();
  }

  showSignedIn(session) {
    console.log('Session: ', session);
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button (click)="login()">Login</button>
```