# Angular App (Version 7.2) doesn't work on Firefox on localhost

Tags: angular, firefox, angular-cli, angular-routing, polyfills

I have an Angular app (version 7.2) that suddenly doesn't in Firefox when I open it on localhost. The browser says: "TLS handshake with localhost is in progress", but after a while I get a timeout. In Chrome and all other browsers, the app works without problems.

I noticed that although it can be called in Firefox, if I have the following settings in the angular.json (ssl property set to false):

```
     "serve": {
       "builder": "@angular-devkit / build-angular: dev-server",
       "options": {
         "browserTarget": "my-ui: build",
         "port": 8080,
         "ssl": false, // set it to false here
         "proxyConfig": "src / proxy.conf.js"
       },
```

However, this way my app does not work anymore, because everything (login, guards, etc.) is based on SSL.

Why does Firefox suddenly have this behavior and how can I solve this problem and still be able to use SSL?

Comment: Setup and import a local host certificate if you want to run it with https on localhost.
See there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44055209/3634274

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get angular-cli to ng serve over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210467/get-angular-cli-to-ng-serve-over-https)

Comment: @JohnnyDevNull The app already runs on https on localhost (in Chrome and other browsers), but not in Firefox.

Comment: Did you import the certificate in firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting my localhost cert and restarting the app worked for me.

http://talk.manageiq.org/t/solved-firefox-performing-a-tls-handshake-is-slow/3046/11