# Run angular with ssl

Tags: angular, ssl

I want to run my angular (7+) project with ssl certificate on localhost ( https://localhost:4200).

I tried the following from this link source - [Get angular-cli to ng serve over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210467/get-angular-cli-to-ng-serve-over-https):

1) **angular.json**

```
{
 "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
 "projects": {
   "<PROJECT-NAME>": {
       "architect": {
           "serve: {
               "options": {
                   "sslKey": "<relative path from angular.json>/server.key",
                   "sslCert": "<relative path from angular.json>/server.crt",
                   ...
               }, ...
             }, ...
         }, ...
     }, ...
 }, ...
```

}

2) **browser-sync**

```
ng serve --ssl true --ssl-key /node_modules/browser-sync/lib/server/certs/server.key --ssl-cert /node_modules/browser-sync/lib/server/certs/server.crt
```

When I am running: `ng serve--ssl` I am getting this log:

> ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on https://localhost:4200/ **

**In browser**

[image]

Comment: is your certificate self signed?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Browsers trust localhost the same as https

Comment: @JohKane yes - generated it with https://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/

Comment: @bryan60 yes, but facebook sdk doesn't

Comment: I've used the facebook sdk over localhost plenty of times, not sure what you're talking about... they're fully aware developers need to run in a localhost environment

Comment: @bryan60 yes, you are right ... I am getting some logs in the console that sounds like ( from fb sdk ): method not working anymore on http://domain.  I have tried initially to fix the issue from fb app settings, didn't work and now...here we are

Comment: this is an xy problem... you want to achieve x but you're asking how to achieve y in order to accomplish x.  I'd instead ask how to handle the specific error from fb and mention that you've attempted running angular over ssl as a solution

Comment: @bryan60 thanks for the suggestion Bryan !!

Comment: @que1326 I believe that you will see that when you self sign a certificate

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are writing code in a Windows dev environment but if you are here are the steps you'll need to run through to make this happen

1. Install Chocolatey (to install OpenSSL for Windows)
2. Install OpenSSL
3. Create OpenSSL Certificate
4. Install Certificate
5. Update npm package.json **start** script

Rather than copy the steps in detail here, I'll link to a guide I've built on how to do this for Windows dev environments as well as an Angular SSL starter project I've built out

- Configuring Angular 12+ with SSL on Windows Dev Environments

  - https://www.briangetsbinary.com/angular/software%20engineering/2021/09/20/angular-cli-configuring-ssl.html
- ngssl Github starter project

  - https://github.com/BrianMikinski/ngssl